# Filter function for cells with Date Time values

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a spreadsheet where the cells in column A are in Date Time format (`DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM`)

I am trying to filter only cells where Date Time values are greater than the current time

I have tried to use various forms such as `DATAVALUE` and `TIMEVALUE`, `TEXT`, but in all of them when I try to use the `FILTER` function it delivers all cells as if they were all future dates, but they are not.

Note, the cell I am trying to use `FILTER` is I2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste this in **`I2`** cell:

```
=FILTER(A2:A, A2:A-I1>0, A2:A<>"")
```

[image: 0]

---

paste this in **`J2`** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(I2:I<>"", I2:I-I1, ))
```